# Imprimir fecha y hora en respuesta al usuario

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el formato de fecha y hora dentro del Script, pero me veo en el problema de no poder incluirlo Como lo haría en otra situación, ingresando un valor dentro de la impresión del mensaje. Tengo el código de dos formas:

**Forma 1**:

```
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.now()

def tiempo():

    if dt.time() < datetime.time(12):
        print("dias")`
    elif dt.time() > datetime.time(12):
        print("tardes")

nombre = input("Por favor ingrese su nombre: ")

print("Buenas",tiempo(),nombre, "que duda tiene?: ")
```

En esta primera forma se ve así:

> Por favor ingrese su nombre: Nombre De Prueba
>   **tardes**
>   Buenas **None** Nombre De Prueba que duda tiene?:

---

*Forma 2*:

```
import datetime


dt = datetime.datetime.now()

tiempo = dt.time() < datetime.time(12), dt.time() > datetime.time(12)

if tiempo == True: print("dias")

elif tiempo == True: print("tardes")


nombre = input("Por favor ingrese su nombre: ")

print("Buenas", tiempo, nombre, "que duda tiene?: ")
```

*En esta segunda se ve asi:*

> Por favor ingrese su nombre: Nombre De Prueba
>   Buenas **(False, True)** Nombre De Prueba que duda tiene?:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema de tu función es que cuando es llamada imprime el string correspondiente pero retorna `None` (retorno por defecto de todo método en Python) y es este `None` el que te imprime tu `print`.

Tu función debe retornar el string adecuado (usando `return`) y no imprimirlo. Al retornar la cadena si puedes llamarla directamente 
desde tu `print` y usar su retorno para imprimir, concatenado como haces o usando `str.format`:

```
import datetime

def tiempo():
    dt = datetime.datetime.now()
    if dt.time() < datetime.time(12):
        return "dias"
    else:
        return "tardes"

nombre = input("Por favor ingrese su nombre: ")
print("Buenas {} {}, ¿qué duda tiene?: ".format(tiempo(), nombre))
```

Tu segunda forma tiene un problema parecido, la variable `tiempo` debería almacenar el string o usar el condicional en el `print`. Usando el operador ternario podría quedar así:

```
import datetime

tiempo = "dias" if datetime.datetime.now().hour < 12 else "tardes"
nombre = input("Por favor ingrese su nombre: ")

print("Buenas", tiempo, nombre, "que duda tiene?: ")
```

Una opción más compacta pero menos legible es:

```
from datetime import datetime

print("Buenas {} {}, ¿qué duda tiene?: ".format("dias" if datetime.now().hour < 12 else "tardes", 
                                                input("Por favor ingrese su nombre: ")))
```

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias FJ

Comment: De nada @FrancoB, bienvenido a [es.so] :). Un saludo.